# How do we send the jsPDF output to the backendapi service using post method in angular 8?

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, jspdf

I have using jsPDF to generate the pdf in my angular web. i would like to send the output of jsPDF to my backend service. could you please any one can help me to do that. Thanks in advance.

```
const URI = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
let fileWidth = 100;
      let PDF = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
      PDF.addImage(URI, 'PNG', fileWidth);
      PDF.save('test.pdf');
```